# Android programmatically connect to device via WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

My app needs to connect to an external device (camera) via WiFi (the device is a local network access point). When I connect to the device's WiFi via Android settings, everything works fine, but I've got a requirement that the user should be able to connect with the device right from the app.

I know that there is an option to connect to a specific network via [WifiManager.addNetwork](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)) but 1) it not always connects me to the network I added 2) this method is deprecated and will stop working when my app targets API 29 (which will happen soon).

I know that the proposed solution  for deprecated `addNetwork` is [suggestion API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest), but it is available only on Android 10 and above (and my app supports API 21).

Are there any other stable options for connecting to a WiFi network (with no internet access) from the app that are available from API 21 and will be working when I'm targeting API 29?

**edit**:
Ok, now I see that for my use case the [Network Request API for peer-to-peer connection](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap) is more suitable, but still - it works only for Android 10 +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months working on this case I now know that:

1. Android documentation is not really correct about the old connection API not working when you target Android 10. It still works on devices with Android < 10. So if you target API 29 and above, you have to write two separate logics for Andoid <10 and >=10...
2. In my opinion, the new connection API sucks. I use this [new peer-to-peer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap) API, and it takes much longer to connect, the system popup is always in English, and there are some connection (eg. in terms of using streams, reconnecting, or video streaming) issues when you connect from the app vs when you connect from settings.

It seems that Google gave as a new solution that is not really stable (some issues are fixed only in Android 11) and force us to use it.  Not really happy about it, but what can you do...

Comment: Yeah it sucks a lot on Android 10. The API on Android 11 is much nicer, but on some devices like OnePlus, Settings Activity just crashes. Connecting to WiFi on Android is a PITA.

Comment: @Cheesebaron is there a different API on Android 11? Could you share a link to that?

Comment: It is a bit hidden in the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS I've written about it here: https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2020/11/android-11-wifi.html

Comment: Thanks. I haven't heard of this new approach. However, this seems to be designed for suggestion API - I'm wondering if this will also work for networks that don't provide internet. Anyway, since it's only for android 11+ and is doesn't work on some targeted devices, this doesn't give us much hope for 10.

Comment: I would say it is more similar to the old API where you added a WiFi network through WiFiManager, just with a confirmation.

Comment: hey @Mohru Can you share please what's the model of wi-fi camera you are using for tests? Are using RTSP stream or some other approach? Thanks

Comment: @RossStepaniak I'm not really allowed to share this information, but it was using RTSP streaming.